# Restrict Incoming Static NAT Connections by Source IP

Tags: networking, cisco, nat

I need to allow connections to several hosts inside my network from a trusted third party. Currently this is achieved with static NAT entries for each server which is proving to be a security nightmare. Is there a way to restrict the incoming connections based on source IP address? I'm thinking maybe a route map could help me achieve this but I need some assistance configuring this setup and/or another solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

a route map can be an elegant solution but the straightforward one for me would me a static nat entry as you have already with an ACL that limits inbound traffic on those NATed ports only from certain incoming ips.

ip access-list *somenumberabove100 for an extended acl* 
-> permit etc etc

If you give me an example of what kind of ports and source ips you want allowed i can concoct a few acl statements.